# auto sum at the ends of each group of data vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on a costing system that will pull line items out of a database depending on the filter criteria I have in my macro. It will pull these line items onto another sheet and group them into sections. So for each system these section sizes could be different sizes, different number of rows each time. What I need is a subtotal line below each section but I can't get the formulas to work correctly since the sections can change sizes the formula is constantly different. I need the AutoSum function from excel but I need to be able to put it in a macro and I'm not sure how to do that. Below is the code I am using to add my first subtotal line. In the end there will be about 5 different sections so there will be 5 different subtotals and I will also need an overall total which I'm not sure how to do either because like I said these sections may change size periodically. Any help is much appreciated.

```
'To add subtotal
    Range("B11").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Select
        Selection.Font.Bold = True
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlRight
        .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = False
    End With
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Subtotal"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-11]C:R[-2]C)"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-11]C:R[-2]C)"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-11]C:R[-2]C)"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-11]C:R[-2]C)"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-11]C:R[-2]C)"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-11]C:R[-2]C)"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-11]C:R[-2]C)"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-11]C:R[-2]C)"
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-11]C:R[-2]C)"
```

Comment: Have you looked into creating a Pivot table? That should do the job nicely. And you can feed it directly from a database if you wish to do so...

Comment: I actually figured it out by just using a macro to run the Subtotal function. I appreciate the response though.